# Giving users a certain amount of tries until program exits

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm creating a method where the user puts in a "PIN" number to access different methods.. Yes it's an ATM..

I'm trying to figure out how to make it so that the user gets a specific amount of tries until the program `exit`'s..

After a bunch of research I haven't very well found anything useful.. The only thing I've found is to use `.to_s.split(//)` in order to add the number of the try into an empty array. Which doesn't make sense to me because why would you make an integer into a string..?

So my question is, how do you make it so that users only have a certain amount of tries, 3, until they get kicked out of the program?

Main source:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

################
#ATM Rewrite 
#                                
#Creator Lost Bam      Not completed yet.
#                        
#11/19/15                
##################

require_relative 'checking.rb'
require_relative 'savings.rb'
require_relative 'exit.rb'
require_relative 'loan.rb'
require_relative 'transfer.rb'
require_relative 'redirect.rb'

class ATM
    attr_accessor :name, :checking_account, :savings_account, :pin_number, :transfer, :loan
        def initialize( name, checking_account, savings_account )
            @name = name
            @checking_account = checking_account
            @savings_account = savings_account
            @pin_number = pin_number
        end
    end
    ##############
    def pin
        x = []
        puts "Enter PIN Number:"
        input = gets.chomp.to_i
        if input == 1234
            menu
        else
            x += 1.to_s.split(//) #<= This is what I found to convert integer to Array
            puts "Invalid PIN, try again:"
            input = gets.chomp
            if x == 3
                bad_pin
            end
        end
    end
    ############
    def menu #add #{name} on line 41
        puts <<-END.gsub(/^\s*>/, ' ')
            >
            >Welcome thank you for choosing Bank of Bam.
            >You may choose from the list below of what you would like to do
            >For checking inquiries press '1'
            >For savings account information press '2'
            >To transfer funds press '3'
            >To either apply for a loan, or get information on a loan press '4'
            >To exit the system press '5'
            >
        END
        input = gets.chomp
        case input.to_i
        when 1
            checking_information
        when 2
            savings_information
        when 3
            transfer_funds
        when 4
            loan_info
        when 5
            exit_screen
        else
            puts "Invalid option please try again"
            menu
        end
    end

    def bad_pin
        abort('Invalid PIN exiting sytem..')
        exit
    end
    pin
```

---

---

Tried something new:

```
def pin
    x = 3
    puts "Enter PIN(#{x} attempts left):"
    pin_num = gets.chomp
    case pin_num.to_i
    when 1234
        menu
    else
        puts "Invalid PIN"
        x -=1
        return pin
        if x == 0
            bad_pin
        end
    end
end
```

It doesn't increment the number down it just keeps saying 3 tries left:

```
Enter PIN(3 attempts left):
4567
Invalid PIN
Enter PIN(3 attempts left):
45345
Invalid PIN
Enter PIN(3 attempts left):
6456
Invalid PIN
Enter PIN(3 attempts left):
4564
Invalid PIN
```

Comment: Why `x` is an array instead of being a simple counter?

Comment: Yes, why not `x = 1` and just increment it at each trial?

Comment: @EricPlaton I tried this, but I incremented down, it doesn't work.. Edited the test run into the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that every time you recall the method the value of `x` resets again. You need to have a loop inside the pin method that'll keep track of attempts.

```
def pin
    x = 3
    while (x > 0) do 
        puts "Enter PIN(#{x} attempts left):"
        pin_num = gets.chomp
        case pin_num.to_i
        when 1234
            menu
        else
            puts "Invalid PIN"
            x -=1
            puts "no tries left" if x == 0
            break if x == 0
        end
    end
end
```

Stay in the method. Recalling the method starts you back at three attempts.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with a loop, thank you!

Comment: Of course... Just remember the scope rules. Google "Ruby Scope" to read up a little bit if you need to.